# What does my HTML need to look like when I autosave in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a couple models and I am not sure how to write me HTML forms in order for the controller to automatically pick them up and save them.

I have a couple models

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :specialties
end

class Specialty < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job
end
```

For simplicity, say each has a name and description.

I want a form where the user can create a job and its specialties at the same time. Right now, my views just use `<%= render 'form' %>` but I expect that will have to change. This is basically what I am looking for:

[image]

Is this possible with autosave? How does Rails know which inputs to take for the specialties? How do I markup those forms?

Bonus points for suggestions on how to structure the markup, e.g. partials, layouts, etc. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the RailsCast for nested model forms. It was exactly what I needed.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Answer (score 1):

you should use a gem called cocoon do add specialties dynamicly like you want:

check out this demo app here: http://mighty-beach-7520.herokuapp.com/projects/new

if you need the source code of that app you can find it here: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo

also, that code is in slim if you need it in ERB i can give you an example of what it looks like